# How can I use log level FINE without summoning an infinite stream of platform debug logging?

Tags: java, applet, java.util.logging

I'd like to use java util logging in my applet, at log level FINE and below.

I've put a `logging.properties` file in my applet's jar which says

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
```

and in my applet class, I feed it to the log manager using

```
logManager.readConfiguration(getClass().getResourceAsStream("logging.properties"));
```

This successfully causes my debug logging to appear in the applet's console window, however as I should've expected, the java platform also begins to log its FINE level messages to the console.

Worse, the act of logging a message to the Java console, of itself, causes more AWT logging(!) This generates an infinite loop of messages in my console along the lines of

```
20:31:55 java.awt.mixing.Component FINE: this = javax.swing.JTextArea[...]
20:31:55 java.awt.mixing.Container FINE: this = javax.swing.JViewport[...]
```

I thought this should be easy to fix by adding

```
java.level=INFO
javax.level=INFO
sun.level=INFO
```

to my logging.properties file.

However, this does not work. The platform logging keeps spewing out, no matter what I write in the properties file.

I've dived into the source code. The LogManager appears to be keeping two different LoggingContexts. One for the user, one system context. My logging.properties file only affects the Loggers in the user LoggingContext, and therefore cannot influence the platform logging's settings.

The LogManager does share the rootLogger between the user LoggingContext and the system LoggingContext. And when I set its level to FINE, I get the infinite stream of awt blurb as a side effect.

So my question is: How can I get my user context's Loggers to log at level FINE by default but keep the system loggers at INFO level?

Comment: Don't say .level=FINE. Just set levels for your classes. Or switch to log4j.

Comment: @bmargulies Is java util logging really so badly designed then? On my way to getting here I've tried to configure the logging using applet `<param>` tags ([forbidden!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources)), run into a bug where some versions don't set the ConsoleHandler on the root logger, and run into breaking changes between Java 6 and Java 7. This is getting a little frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried to do the same thing, but in a web start application. I needed to have java.util.logging set to FINEST in order to find some problems in the application. It didn't matter what I did, the Swing logging just kept on spewing.

Your question, and investigation that you had done helped me solving the problem, albeit in a very ugly way, but I only needed it temporarily. I grabbed the system loggers using reflection:

```
    public static void tryToChangeSystemLogContextLoggers() {
    try {
        Field systemContextField = LogManager.class.getDeclaredField("systemContext");
        systemContextField.setAccessible(true);
        Object systemContext = systemContextField.get(LogManager.getLogManager());
        Method demandLoggerMethod = systemContext.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("demandLogger", String.class, String.class);
        demandLoggerMethod.setAccessible(true);
        java.util.logging.Logger logger = (java.util.logging.Logger)demandLoggerMethod.invoke(systemContext, "java.awt", null);
        logger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.WARNING);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        logger = (java.util.logging.Logger)demandLoggerMethod.invoke(systemContext, "sun.awt", null);
        logger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.WARNING);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        logger = (java.util.logging.Logger)demandLoggerMethod.invoke(systemContext, "javax.swing", null);
        logger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.WARNING);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Well, I tried
    }
}
```

The code is fragile, and might not work in all java version.

Comment: Ruthless quick and dirty solution. I like it!